C#: Sending SSDP Requests to 239.255.255.250
I am trying to find DIAL Servers on my network by sending a SSDP Request to the Multicast Address 239.255.255.250. The Code for this is as follows:
using (UdpClient udpClient = new UdpClient())
   {
      IPAddress multicastIP = IPAddress.Parse("239.255.255.250");
      IPEndPoint multicastEndpoint = new IPEndPoint(multicastIP, 1900);
      var requestData = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(
          "M-SEARCH * HTTP/1.1\r\n" +
          "HOST: 239.255.255.250:1900\r\n" +
          "MAN: \"ssdp:discover\"\r\n" +
          "MX: 3\r\n" +
          "ST: urn:dial-multiscreen-org:service:dial:1\r\n" +
          "\r\n");
       udpClient.Send(requestData, requestData.Length, multicastEndpoint);
       //receiver logic...
   }

however when I check for these packets in Wireshark they dont show up (I tried both "ssdp" as well as "udp &&  ip.addr==192.168.2.106" as filters, with 192.168.2.106 being the sender address)
Since sending to any other Address works I assume it has something to do with it being a multicast address, similar to what is being described in this thread Unable to use UdpClient to multicast to "239.255.255.250". However I am not sure if I can use DatagramSocket, because it seems to be using the UWP namespace and I am in Dotnet (if that makes any sense)
I have also attempted using the RSSP Package https://github.com/Yortw/RSSDP, but that only shows services running on my localhost for some reason.

Did you read this : "If you want to send datagrams to any other broadcast address [as the default one], use the Client method to obtain the underlying Socket, and set the socket option to SocketOptionName.Broadcast. You can also revert to using the Socket class." - Docs -> Example here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.sockets.udpclient.client?view=net-8.0#examples

@Fildor I have tried this
{
    Socket uSocket = udpClient.Client;
    uSocket.SetSocketOption(SocketOptionLevel.Socket,
                  SocketOptionName.Broadcast, 1);
    udpClient.Client = uSocket;

    IPAddress multicastIP = IPAddress.Parse("239.255.255.250");...``` 
but no success. am I using this correctly?

You can directly call udpClient.Client.SetSocketOption(SocketOptionLevel.Socket,                   SocketOptionName.Broadcast, 1); - but if the Client property is R/W then that should make no difference, really. If it's still not working, though ... no idea. Last time I broadcasted UDP was 15 years ago in a different language :( Maybe check if that port is throwing you off. I faintly remember you couldn't just use any arbitrary port for broadcast. I am also not sure if you need to join the group to send - I was under the impression you don't need to, but meh.

Maybe also check your router's feature set. I would guess it should support UDP Broadcast, but if you check you can say you checked it. (In fact, if you have a wider topology of connected routers and switches, you may want to check all of them).

@Fildor
also not sure about "from" ports, only that you need to send to 1900. I have checked wireshark for other applications that send SSDPs and they don't seem to be sending from any particular port.
I couldn't find any information about if my Router supports UDP Broadcasting, but since applications such as Chrome have no issue finding the DIAL Server I assume it does.
I have tried adding udpClient.JoinMulticastGroup(multicastAddr);, but to no avail
